# Derivative of $f(x)= \sqrt{x}tan(x)$ at point $0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x)=\sqrt{x}\tan(x)$, if I derivate this function, I'll get $f'(x)= \dfrac{\tan(x)}{2\sqrt{x}} +\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\cos^2{x}}$. And the domain is $(0;\infty)$, so we can't calculate $f'(0)$, but if we use that: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x}\tan(x)-0}{x-0} = 0$, how?

Comment: Unify the denominators and then use the L'Hopitale rule again

Answer (score -1):

> Using L'Hôpital's rule twice

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac {\sqrt {x}\tan(x)}{x}＝\lim_{x\to0}\frac {\tan(x)}{2\sqrt {x}}＋\frac {\sqrt {x}}{\cos^2(x)}＝\lim_{x\to0}\frac {\sin(x)\cos(x)＋2x}{2\sqrt {x}\cos^2(x)}$$

And therfore
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac {\sin(x)\cos(x)＋2x}{2\sqrt {x}\cos^2(x)}＝\lim_{x\to0}\frac {\cos^2(x)－\sin^2(x)＋2}{\textstyle\frac {\cos^2(x)}{\sqrt {x}}－4\sqrt {x}\sin(x)\cos(x)}＝\lim_{x\to0}\;\frac {\sqrt {x}(\cos^2(x)－\sin^2(x)＋2)}{\cos^2(x)－4x\sin(x)\cos(x)}=0$$